# Paper size per printer?

Tags: printing

I have a laser printer and a label printer. I need to print from PDF to both. Is there no way to have the page settings set per printer and not system wide?

Now each time I swap to use the other printer I have to go in and change between A4 and the custom size for the label printer.. It would be great if I just had to choose the printer and the paper size would change according to that selection.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.5 but it does not seem to differ in 20.04?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could open the "Printers" Dialog:
[image]

Select "Properties" in the contextmenu:
[image]

There you can set the page size. So depending on the selected printer, you'll get the correct size.

Comment: Thanks but the Print dialog->Page Setup->Paper Size overrides that so the Paper Size is always set to what I left it at no matter which printer I select. I'll test this on Ubuntu 20.04 also as this is on 18.04.5..

Comment: Also, in the print dialog I can setup a custom size with exact measures (x, y). In the Printer Options there is a Custom option but not sure how to set its values?

Comment: Ok- don't tell me that you are using LibreOffice - it has its own printerdriver. Use a pdfviewer to select your printers, not LibreOffice...

Comment: No, I'm using a pdf-viewer. And I'm talking about the normal ctrl-p dialog that comes up from Firefox for example.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Evince or Atril as your PDF viewer?

They save the print settings of the last print command - nearly all of the settings. This isn't done just for the last chosen printer, but for all printers. So you get errors if you print an A3 page on an A3-Printer and the the next time on an A4-Printer, if you don't change the paper size to A4.

You can prevent saving all settings of the print dialog by making the file unchangeable:

```
cd .config/atril/
rm print-settings
touch print-settings
sudo chattr +i print-settings
```

Reverse:

```
sudo chattr -i print-settings
```

Or better, use qpdfview.